# MySQL parameterization in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby

Is there any MySQL library for Ruby that supports parameterization? The documentation for mysql2 gives this example:

```
escaped = client.escape("gi'thu\"bbe\0r's")
results = client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE group='#{escaped}'")
```

And that seems kind of clunky and screw-up-able to me.

Comment: You could always fall back to raw SQL prepared statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/prepared_statements_rdoc.html) does, too. But for MySQL it only simulates them:

> The MySQL ruby driver does not support bound variables, so the bound variable methods fall back to string interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently DBI does
http://ruby-dbi.rubyforge.org/